# Understanding table constraint in SQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, postgresql

I faced with the the system [table_contraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/infoschema-table-constraints.html). Now, I'm writing a class `TableConstraint` representing a table constraint itself. Is the `table_constraint` the `postgreSQL`-speciefic concept or I can safely use the class if I migrate to, say `MSSQL` or something else `RDBMS`?

```
public abstract class TableConstraint{

    private String name;
    private String tableName;
    //GET, SET
}
```

Comment: All (proper) databases have constraints in some form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the table_constraint the postgreSQL-speciefic concept

No. It's a part of ANSI `information_schema` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema)

> I can safely use the class if I migrate to, say MSSQL or something else RDBMS?

It depends. Not all RDBMS supports `information_schema` (Oracle for instance doesn't). However quick look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx and we know SQL Server implements it.

Answer (score 1):

The `table_constraints` view is a part of [information schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema). It's a part of [the standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt). It is rather safe to assume a modern db will stick to the standard however, like with all the standards, that's not always. true.

It certainly exists in latest versions of:

- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)
- [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/information-schema.html)
- [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx)

It doesn't exist (or I haven't found info about it) in:

- SQLite
- Oracle (as pointed out by Radek)

Comment: Oracle doesn't have `information_schema`. Your link points to the MySQL docs.

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz Thx.